# Exception causing Log.e() to be skipped

Tags: java, android, exception, try-catch

I have the following code that I'm trying to debug:

```
public Cursor getUpdateTimestamps() {
    Cursor timestamps;
    try {
        // int j = 3 / 0; // This will throw a divide-by-zero exception

        timestamps = this.read_db.query(UPDATES_TABLE, new String[] { C_ID, U_C_TABLE, U_C_LAST_UPDATE }, null, null, null, null, null);

        return timestamps;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e(TAG, "An error occurred in getUpdateTimestamps(): " + e.getMessage() + " | " + e.getCause());
        return null;
    }
}
```

I set my breakpoint on the line where `timestamps` is being set to `this.read_db.query...` and start my debugger on my connected device (Samsung Galaxy S3).

When I reach the breakpoint, I step over to the next statement, which causes an exception to be thrown. However, instead of going to the first line in my `catch` block, the debugger skips directly to my `return null` statement without logging my error message. It also skips over any calls to `System.out.println`.

When I uncomment `int j = 3 / 0;` the proper exception is thrown and caught, and the error message is logged.

What type of exception could be causing the `Log.e()` method to be completely ignored?

**UPDATE:** I've also noticed the following stack trace in my log, but can't be sure that it has anything to do with this issue:

```
06-07 11:57:44.717    1757-1757/?                              W/System.err: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConstraintException: column packagename is not unique (code 19)
06-07 11:57:44.717    1757-1757/?                              W/System.err: at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativeExecuteForChangedRowCount(Native Method)
06-07 11:57:44.717    1757-1757/?                              W/System.err: at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.executeForChangedRowCount(SQLiteConnection.java:857)
06-07 11:57:44.717    1757-1757/?                              W/System.err: at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.executeForChangedRowCount(SQLiteSession.java:754)
06-07 11:57:44.717    1757-1757/?                              W/System.err: at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteStatement.executeUpdateDelete(SQLiteStatement.java:64)
06-07 11:57:44.717    1757-1757/?                              W/System.err: at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.executeSql(SQLiteDatabase.java:1665)
06-07 11:57:44.717    1757-1757/?                              W/System.err: at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.execSQL(SQLiteDatabase.java:1594)
```

None of my SQLite tables have a column called `packagename` so this might be unrelated.

Comment: Do other log statements work correctly?

Comment: As stated in the question, `When I uncomment int j = 3 / 0; the proper exception is thrown and caught, and the error message is logged.`

Comment: What happens if you try to catch a Throwable?

Comment: Same thing - skips any calls to output methods (`t.printStackTrace()`, `Log.e(...)` and goes directly to the `return` statement.

Comment: The logact output you posted looks exactly like what I would expect from a database query exception.
Have you tried using `Log.e(String, String, Throwable)` instead of `Log.e(String, String)`?

Comment: @Tanis.7x now I see `E/SQLiteLog: (5) statement aborts at 1: [PRAGMA journal_mode=TRUNCATE;]`

Answer (score 0):

The behaviour that you have described very similar to the situation, when you haven't rebuild your project before new debug iteration.

When you uncomment mentioned line, debugger begins *see* line with  `Log.e(TAG, "...` in correct position.

I'm sure, that if you will stop debugging and rebuild project - everything will be ok.

Comment: I did a clean & build. No dice - same problem.